# SPARQL property paths in Oracle Jena Adapter and Jena ARQ

Tags: oracle, sparql, jena

I am using Oracle Jena Adapter. My problem is about property paths on SPARQL queries. When I tried to query

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?t rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty.
  ?t rdfs:domain ?o.
  ?o owl:unionOf ?union.
  ?union rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?member.
}
```

from ModelOracleSem it gives me a parser error. But, if I try it using a Jena in-memory model, it works perfectly as below:

```java
hybridGraph = OracleGraphWrapperForOntModel.getInstance(graph1);
model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(hybridGraph);
ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, model);
```

I also tried ARQ's list function as `?union list:member ?member`. It does not return any results from ModelOracleSem. But when I try it from a Jena in-memory model, it works perfectly again.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

**Edit :**
You can see the exact error message below. Version info: Jena 2.6.4, ARQ 2.8.8, Jena Adapter 11.2.0.3 Thanks,

> 2013-06-10 16:54:42 message: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: oracle.spatial.rdf.server.ParseException: Encountered "<" at line 1, column 2.
>
> Was expecting one of:

```
 <URI> ... 
 <QNAME> ... 
 <VAR> ...
```

> ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T", line 203 ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T", line 67 ORA-06512: at line 4

Comment: I have not used the Jena Oracle adapter, but I wonder if this is an issue of which versions the adapter supports, and which version of ARQ you are using.  Which version of the Jena Oracle adapter are you using?   Which version of Jena/ARQ are you using for your in memory tests?  Also, could you should the parse error that you are getting?  It might help to diagnose which versions of the language the different parsers are expecting.

Comment: I think there's still something we're not seeing.  Either that parse error is arising from something else, or the query you are showing us is not complete.  The parse error says `Encountered "<" at line 1, column 2.` but there is not a `<` in the query that you have shown us.

Comment: I am aware of it is very strange. But when I run the query as `?union rdf:rest/rdf:first ?member.` (without *) it works perfectly. And also when running the query with same code by using in-memory jena model, it works again without an error.

Comment: After some Googling on MDSYS.RDF_MATCH_IMPL_T and seeing some posts like [this one](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/908347?tstart=75), it looks like the adapter translates some things, so I expect that some of the translated query has the text that is causing the parser error.  (That doesn't help all that much for a solution, but it might be a start.)

Answer (score 0):

As Joshua has stated your question is missing some important information e.g. the parser error given.

The Oracle Jena adaptor should support property paths, to quote their [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11828/sem_jena.htm#insertedID5):

> The Jena Adapter supports all Jena property path types through the
>   integration with the Jena ARQ query engine

Therefore as Joshua suggests this may be a case of a version mismatch, are you using an old version of the Oracle Jena Adapter but a newer version of Jena.

On the subject of `list:member` that is an ARQ property function which is a non-standard SPARQL extension.  The documentation does not mention this at all so I would assume it is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the jena adapter and I can confirm that the jena adapter is sensitive to the version of jena being used. I have not encountered this particular problem, but I have experienced similar problems when using a newer version of jena with an older version of the jena adapter.

The jena adapter (I don't remember the version number right now) compatible with jena 2.6.4 and ARQ 2.8.8 threw a runtime exception when we tried executing CONSTRUCT-queries using Jena 2.9.2. We had to downgrade in order to make it work properly.

With the correct versions of jena/jena adapter we have experienced that property paths with a * works, but it runs very slow (a bit too slow for us ;)).